# query to sum a column until get defined value

Tags: mysql

i've tried some other topics for this but couldn't get answers that meet my requirement so posting a new question. sorry bout this.

i'm trying to query on mysql to get a 'sum' data until it reaches the defined value. like

from my table 'purchase', for each 'sid' starting from the last row, i need sum of 'pqty' until the result equals a value from string (but to try i've given a certain value).
let me define with the rows from my table---
the rows for 'sid=1' from 'purchase' are like this---

> ```
>        date      pqty    prate    pamt
>     2014/04/29    5     38000    190000
>     2014/05/04    1     38000    38000
>     2014/05/13   20     35000    700000
>     2014/05/19    1     38000    38000
> ```

from this row, starting from the last row i want to 'sum(pqty) until it reaches 19(for now). it is achieved from adding last 2 rows(for 19). and stop sum here and return valus or sum of 'pqty', 'prate' and 'pamt'. to achieve this i tried the following according to example found on this forum.

```
SELECT date, pqty, @total := @total + pqty AS total
    FROM (purchase, (select @total :=0) t)
    WHERE @total<19 AND sid = $sid ORDER BY date DESC
```

but it's not working for me. please guide me through this. also suggest something else if this is not the good technique for my purpose.

thankz in advance.....

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET.

Comment: sorry i know less on DDLs or sqlfiddle. so far as my DESIRED RESULT SET, the result should select last to rows to make sum(pqty) '19'

Comment: ok! i found sqlfiddle. here it is - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3b6d76/1

Comment: So, problem solved? !?!?

Comment: no not! i just tested it there. the result is not my solution. i said it should select last 2 rows descending. but it is selecting first 3 rows descending.

Comment: You say 'descending'. Do you mean 'ascending' !?!? (I knew there was a reason why I put DESIRED RESULT SET in BLOCK CAPITALS).

Comment: yes it is descending. not ascending.

Comment: So you want the rows dated 19th and 13th - even though this (20+1) adds up to more than 19

Comment: EDITTED: yes! it should reach 19 and where it gets 19, it should stop at that row. and return that row also where it gets the targeted value. if if is just '2' in stead '19', it should also return '1+20'. but if it is required '22' it should move 1 row up... and likewise...

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% certain, but I think both of these work...

```
 SELECT x.*, SUM(y.pqty) FROM purchase x
   JOIN purchase y
     ON y.date >= x.date
  GROUP
     BY x.date
 HAVING 19 BETWEEN SUM(y.pqty)-x.pqty AND SUM(y.pqty)
     OR 19 >= SUM(y.pqty);


 SELECT a.*
   FROM 
      ( SELECT x.*, @i := @i+pqty i
          FROM purchase x
             , (SELECT @i:= 0) var
         ORDER 
            BY x.date DESC
      ) a
  WHERE 19 BETWEEN a.i-a.pqty AND a.i
     OR 19 >= a.i;
```